# Commas instead of semicolons in MS Access lookup column

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I would not dare label myself as a programmer. But I am running a website with a storefront. I want to label some of my products with multiple categories. This involves creating one column in my MS Access database (called categories) that has categories separated by commas. i.e. "shirts,clothing,wearables,sports"

I've added a lookup column that does this fine and inserts the categories I choose for a particular product. The problem is that when I export my database into a txt file, Excel file, etc... this column shows up with semicolons! "shirts;clothing;wearable;sports"

Now, I could go and replace all semicolons with commas in that column, but I'm hoping there is an easier way to do this within MS Access. Perhaps a setting I am not aware of?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is the rest of the txt file delimited by commas?

Comment: @Tony Toews I believe ms-access-2007 to be an important tag, as do others it seems, because it is widely used.

Comment: This is a website question, so Access is not even involved, only Jet/ACE. In this case, the A2007 tag was provided by the original poster, so I think it should remain, but adding the A2007 tag to questions that aren't specifically about A2007 is really not helpful to anyone at all.

Comment: @David W. Fenton I do not believe that removing relevant tags added by the OP is helpful, either.

Answer (score 0):

Storing a list of items in a field is a design error.

Instead, you should have a table that is related to your main table, and that stores the ProductID (to link it back to a particular product record) and one category per record. Your example data would look like this, assuming ProductID=1:

```
ProductID   Category
    1       shirts
    1       clothing
    1       wearables
    1       sports
```

In a web app, you'd then display the results in a multiselect listbox (you add the "multiple" tag inside your SELECT tag). You'd have to iterate through the list to add the SELECTED tag to the items that have already been chosen.

Comment: "Storing a list of items in a field is a design error." Whose? The Access Team's? See Access2007 Help: Guide to multivalued fields (http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access/HA012337221033.aspx).

Comment: ...Or do you mean it's a First Normal Form (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) violation? "Every row-and-column intersection contains exactly one value from the applicable domain (and nothing else)." It helps to be specific.

Comment: Yes, I believe that multivalue fields are not something that a programmer should ever use. They are also badly designed for end users, as they can only be manipulated through the UI or via complicated VBA code. Multivalue fields were added to the ACCDB format only for compatibility with Sharepoint, not because they were a good idea or proper design.

Comment: So are you saying the "design error" that the OP has committed is a 1NF failure?

Comment: It is a design error because it is a non-optimal design, not because of some abstract adherence to first normal form. The reason we normalize is because non-normalized data structures cause problems, and are, thus, design errors. It is because it is a design error that we aim for the highest level of normalization that is both possible and practical for any particular application. Multivalue fields fail the test on all counts.

Comment: "It is a design error ... not because of some abstract adherence to first normal form." -- what do you mean by 'abstract'? It violates 1NF, period -- "non-normalized data structures...are...design errors" -- it violates 1NF, the design is fatally flawed. 'nuff said.

Comment: You have it backwards -- it is not a design error because it violates 1NF. The reason 1NF exists is to describe the correct ways of avoiding these design errors. 1NF is the codification of a set of principles that allow you to avoid the design error. Violating 1NF is entirely a secondary point, and not the design error itself.

Comment: I agree with your last comment but only up to a point. When denormalization is performed as an explicit design choice the question of whether this is erroneous becomes subjective. Therefore, pointing out that the design violates 1NF's requirement for scalar data types is more objective and suffices in this case.

Comment: On a more practical point, do you agree that editing this answer to include the 1NF violation would improve it? I fear these comments may be a distraction for anyone reading the answer.

Comment: I don't see that anything is added by refering to 1NF in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem in the oddest place.

I wanted a TAB delimited file just as I created it in Access. But if I used commas in a field, Access replaced them with semi-colons. I exported to Excel and tried that, but although Excel was kind enough to leave my commas, it placed quotation marks around that field when exported to the TAB file.

SOLUTION: Google Documents. Simply upload an Excel file (exported from Access), then save to a TAB file. Google doesn't fool with your data and you get the file you want ready for import. In this case, it is being imported into MIVA Merchant. A horrible piece of... software used for e-commerce. But if anyone else out there is using it, don't bother purchasing all those modules and macros that enable you to do what Excel or Access should do in the first place until you've checked out this free and pretty easy work around.

Comment: I see no reason you shouldn't have been able to do this export from Access.